# Error con matrices en Python

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy tratando de obtener el determinante de una matriz con ayuda de numpy.linalg.det(matriz) este es el codigo:

```
from sympy import *
#from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from py_expression_eval import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#[1,2] es una fila
#[3,4] otra fila
M = [[1,2], [3,4]]
def matrixDet(matrix):
    return np.linalg.det(matrix)
M2 = input("Ingrese la matriz de la forma [1, 2] (esto es una fila), [3, 2] (esto es otra fila)")
print(matrixDet(M2))
```

el metodo funciona si le paso la matriz M pero al pasarle la matriz M2 no la reconoce aunque la pase igual [[1,2], [3,4]]

Me da el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Calculadoras Metodos/matrices/matrixDeterminante.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(matrixDet(M2))
  File "F:/Calculadoras Metodos/matrices/matrixDeterminante.py", line 11, in matrixDet
    return np.linalg.det(matrix)
  File "C:\Users\DanielPortatil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 1817, in det
    _assertRankAtLeast2(a)
  File "C:\Users\DanielPortatil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 202, in _assertRankAtLeast2
    'at least two-dimensional' % len(a.shape))
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

Comment: ¿Cómo quieres que el usuario ingrese la matriz como `[1,2][3,4]` o `[[1,2],[3,4]]`?

Comment: Creo que es mejor que la ingrese asi [1,2][3,4] para que le sea lo mas sencillo posible pero de la otra forma tambien esta bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no le estas pasando una matriz sino una cadena de texto, si quieres ingresar la matriz de la forma que lo haces necesitas parsear el string de entrada y pasarlo a una lista de listas o a un array bidimencional de Numpy.

- **Entrada de la forma `"[1,2][3,4]"`:**

  Una opción es usar `split` junto a expresiones regulares para construir la matriz a partir de la cadena.

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import re


  def matrixDet(matrix):
      return np.linalg.det(matrix)

  def parse_matriz(cadena):
      # Entrada: una cadena del tipo '[a,b,c][d,f,e]...'
      # Salida una lista de la forma [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]] contruida con los datos de entrada
      cadena = cadena.replace(" ", "")
      return [[float(n) for n in row.split(',')]
                            for row in re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", cadena)]

  M2 = input("Ingrese la matriz de la forma [1,2] (esto es una fila), [3,2] (esto es otra fila)")
  M2=parse_matriz(M2)
  print('El determinante es:', matrixDet(M2))
  ```

  Partiendo de que el usuario ingresa una cadena  de la forma `'[1,2][3,4]'` que puede o no contener espacios lo primero es eliminarlos con  con `replace(" ", "")`. Hecho esto con `re.findall("\[(.*?)\]", cadena)` obtenemos una lista con las filas de la matriz usando los corchetes como separadores: `['1,2', '3,4']`.

  Ahora solo queda recorrer cada cadena de la lista anterior y separar los números usando la coma, los pasamos a `float` y los metemos dentro de una lista.

.

- **Entrada de la forma `"[[1,2],[3,4]]"`:**

  Al ser una cadena que es código python válido podemos usar `eval()` para pasarla directamente a una lista. No obstante, usar `eval()` para entradas de usuario sin filtrar es muy peligroso y nunca debe usarse. Lo que si podemos usar es la versíon segura [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import ast


  def matrixDet(matrix):
      return np.linalg.det(matrix)

  M2 = ast.literal_eval(input("Ingrese la matriz de la forma [[1,2],[3,4]]: "))

  print('El determinante es:', matrixDet(M2))
  ```

.

Ambas formas admiten espacios entre los elemntos de la matriz y ambas permiten ingresar tanto enteros como floats. Es decir, para el primer caso es válido tanto `[1,2][3,4]` como [`1,2] [3, 4]`, igual que para la segunda forma.

En ambos casos sería oportuno validar la entrada del usuario para evitar excepciones.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias @FJSevilla :D

Answer (score 1):

Hola para solucionar esto use numpy.matrix() el codigo quedo asi:

```
from sympy import *
#from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from py_expression_eval import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#[1,2] es una fila
#[3,4] otra fila
M = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
def matrizDet(matriz):
    matriz = np.matrix(matriz)
    return np.linalg.det(matriz)
M2 = input("Ingrese la matriz de la forma [1, 2] (esto es una fila), [3, 2] (esto es otra fila)")
print(matrizDet(M2))
```

Ahora si me lee los datos que el usuario entre pero el usuario debe ingresarlos asi:
1, 2; 3, 2
De todos modos si alguien conoce una forma de que funcione con la otra forma se lo agradezco